# Zero-pad to chirp signal

Tags: matlab, chirp

I have generated 16 chirps in experimental study:

[image: Time domain data]

and the signal was picked up by some electronic sensor, and then I have calculated the spectrum of the received signal:

[image: spectrum of signal]

Following that I have calculated the cross spectrum density between the sound emitter and receiver and did some post processing, i.e.:

```
x=voltage1(:,2);    
y1=vertgeo1(:,2);

Fs=1000;
window=hamming(512);
noverlap=512/2
nfft=512;Fs=1000;

[Pxy1,f]=cpsd(x,y1,window,noverlap,nfft,Fs);
```

From this code the number of the points that shows the frequency resolution, essentially the number of the point that `f` contains is $1\times 256$.

I would like to know how I can increase this to $1025$ points.

Comment: increase *what*?  the size of the FFT, the size of the window? sure you can.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, Increase the size of FFT, do I need to add zero padding to each chirp or just I need to add it at the end of the signal?

Comment: so the chirp cannot be longer?  if that is the case, you don't want to increase the size of the window, but then zero-pad the windowed signal that you are sending to the FFT.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to zero-pad each chirp. MATLAB's `cspd` function divide the signal into segments of length `nfft`. Would you want is to zero-pad each segment. Luckily for you, the `cspd` function can do it for you. Take a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cpsd.html?refresh=true):

> If $\tt nfft$ is greater than the signal length, the data is zero-padded. If $\tt nfft$ is less than the signal length, the segment is wrapped so that the length is equal to $\tt nfft$.

So what you should do is increase the value of `nfft` from $512$ to $2048$.

Comment: well I want to have a frequency resolution of fs/nfft=1000/2048= 0.488. but I have no idea to do that.

Comment: I do not understand how I can increase my frequency resolution, do I need to add zero padding to the length of my window or doing something else?

Comment: Well, as I wrote in my answer, change the value of nfft to 2048. That would result in frequency interpolation.

Comment: The nfft shouldn't be less than sampling rate?

Comment: No it can also be greater